# fancybox: higher than viewport?

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I am using a fancybox to show some inline content on a listview. My problem is, that when the inline content is higher than the viewport, fancybox creates scrollbars inside the lightbox - but this is not the desiered effect. Instead i would like the lightbox/fancybox to addapt to the inline content, so that the scrollbar will be in the browser itself and not the lightbox.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from api

**autoScale**  =    **true**  =>    If true, FancyBox is scaled to fit in viewport

look on the api document for more option

http://fancybox.net/api

Comment: I already tried that, but just did it again. And then i realized that i had used 'true' when trying, and not true (without the plings). That did the trick.